# Swift list getting and removing value

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

Swift's documentation of Remove from an array is "Removes and returns the element at the specified position."  When I try it I don't get any values.  If I do it in two steps it works fine.  What am I missing?[image: Code and returned values]
Main code:

```
func GetItemAlert(s: String){
    // Create an alert
    let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: "New item",
        message: s,
        preferredStyle: .alert)

    // Add a text field to the alert for the new item's title
    //alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: nil)

    // Add a "cancel" button to the alert. This one doesn't need a handler
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    // Add a "OK" button to the alert. The handler calls addNewItem()
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (_) in

    }))

    // Present the alert to the user
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func pop()-> String{
    let removeid = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(TheList.count)))
    let val1 = TheList[removeid]
    let val2 = TheList.remove(at: removeid)
    tableView.reloadData()
    return ""
}

@IBAction func btnPop(_ sender: Any) {
    GetItemAlert(s: pop())
}
```

Extention:

```
import Foundation

class HatTrick
{
    var item: String
    public init(item: String)
    {
        self.item = item
    }
}

extension HatTrick
    {
        public class func preload() -> [HatTrick]
        {
            return [
                HatTrick(item: "A"),
                HatTrick(item: "B"),
                HatTrick(item: "C"),
                HatTrick(item: "D"),
                HatTrick(item: "E")
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in saying that remove "Removes and returns the element at the specified position."

```
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3] // Creates an array
let b = a.remove(at: 2) // we removed a value from a and stored it in b
print(b) // Prints 2
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why Xcode's debugger isn't showing any details for `val2`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it doesn't show `val2` in the debugger cause Xcode optimized them out. You can try to call a function with them and see whether its still optimized away.

Val1 is still referenced inside the Array until its removed in the next call, so retained? If you care you could file a bugreport.

Comment: When I try to return val2 I get an error "Cannot convert return expression of type 'HatTrick' to return type 'String'"

Comment: HatTrick itself is not a string, but it looks like it has properties that are strings. Maybe try to return or print out val2.item instead?

Comment: Just added the class that defines HatTrick